# PySide Qt tr() does not translate, translate() does - context wrong?

Tags: python, qt4, translation, pyside

I want to use a QTranslator to be able to use English text labels and still have the software showing German labels.

Unfortunately my app does not translate, except when I specify the context.
The following static function instanciates a QApplication and adds the desired translators.

The first print translates 'Apple2' correctly to 'Apfel2'. The context in Qt Linguist also has the context 'app'.
The second print does not translate though. `tr()` calls in classes (defined in the same python file) don't translate either.

```
def load_application():
    app = QApplication()

    qt_translator = QTranslator()
    qt_translator.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(), QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
    app.installTranslator(qt_translator)

    app_translator = QTranslator()
    r = app_translator.load('i18n/' + QLocale.system().name())
    app.installTranslator(app_translator)

    print(app.translate('app', 'Apple2'))
    print(app.tr('Apple'))

    return app
```

**EDIT:**

The part for the static function was correct. The context for the application was QApplication. This did not help with the QMainWindow subclass though. I updated the code accordingly. The context generated by pyside-lupdate for the class is MainWindow:

**view**

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    add_model_widget = None

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # Create menu bar
        menu_bar = QMenuBar(self)
        m_file = QMenu(self.tr('File'), menu_bar)
        a_add_model = QAction(QIcon('add.png'), self.tr('Add Jewel'), self)

        m_file.addAction(a_add_model)
        menu_bar.addMenu(m_file)
        self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)

def load_application():
    app = QApplication()

    app_translator = QTranslator()
    app_translator.load(QLocale.system().name(), 'i18n')
    app.installTranslator(app_translator)

    return app
```

**controller**

```
def initiate():
    model.initiate_mongodb()
    app = view.load_application()

    main_window = view.MainWindow()

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Solution:**
The solution to my problem was that the QTranslator didn't have any parent. QTranslator(app) solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to happen because, unlike Qt, PySide/PyQt determines the context at runtime.

In your example, the context will (I think) resolve to `QApplication` at runtime, whereas the pyside/pyqt lupdate tools will hardcode it as `app`. The tools only do static analysis of the source code, and so I suppose they are not smart enough to figure out what the correct class should be.

The example code *should* work if you do something like this, though:

```
class App(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        message = self.tr('Apple')
...
app = App()
...
print(app.tr('Apple'))
```

(Obviously you will need to update the translation files first).

**EDIT**:

Here's a simplified demo that works for me:

**test.py**:

```
import sys, os
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu(self.tr('File'))
        menu.addAction(self.tr('Hello World'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    translator.load('i18n/tr_de', os.path.dirname(__file__))
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**i18n/tr.pro**:

```
SOURCES = ../test.py
TRANSLATIONS = tr_de.ts
```

**i18n/tr_de.ts**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS><TS version="1.1" language="de_DE">
<context>
    <name>MainWindow</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="../test.py" line="7"/>
        <source>File</source>
        <translation>Datei</translation>
    </message>
    <message>
        <location filename="../test.py" line="8"/>
        <source>Hello World</source>
        <translation>Hallo Welt</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

**command output**:

```
$ pyside-lupdate -verbose -noobsolete i18n/tr.pro
Updating 'tr_de.ts'...
    Found 2 source texts (2 new and 0 already existing)
$ lrelease-qt4 i18n/tr.pro
Updating './i18n/tr_de.qm'...
    Generated 2 translation(s) (2 finished and 0 unfinished)
```

Comment: As I wrote above the translator correctly loads the .qm file. Also app.translate() is working, which is only possible with the correctly loaded translator. I also tried the absolute path, nothing changed.

Comment: @Josch. Your question didn't really make that clear, but anyway, I have updated my answer with a different explanation.

Comment: Yes sorry, I thought it was implied by the working translation of one word.
I also updated my question. Thanks for your affort.

Comment: @Josch. It's impossible to tell from your new example what you might be doing wrong, so I've added a simplified working demo to my answer.

Comment: I compared the solutions, the only difference was that you gave the QTranslator app as the parent. My solution also worked as soon as I did that. Thanks a lot! Can you update your solution? I will mark it as correct then.

Answer (score 5):

If you got here like me, wanting to understand how you should do translation using PySide.

**Use translate()**, not **tr()**

The annoying part about using `tr()` is that you have to manually edit the generated .ts files every time you edit your source with the method he proposes, this editing takes a lot of time especially when you update your .ts file, because it puts all .tr() calls in the "Unknown context" context, you have to manually move all the translations back to the correct contexts again, this gets out of hand really quickly.

Instead, there's a very simple solution.

I read [the official pyqt4-lupdate documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/i18n.html), and it says

> The PyQt4 behaviour is unsatisfactory and may be changed in the
>   future. It is recommended that QCoreApplication.translate() be used in
>   preference to tr() (and trUtf8()). This is guaranteed to work with
>   current and future versions of PyQt4 and makes it much easier to share
>   message files between Python and C++ code. Below is the alternative
>   implementation of A that uses QCoreApplication.translate():

```
from QtCore import QCoreApplication
translate = QCoreApplication.translate

class A(QtCore.QObject):
    def hello(self):
        return translate("A", "Hello")
```

Where "A" is the hard-coded context, which `pyside-lupdate` *will* find. A lot better!

Comment: The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28385477/1) had this title: "PySide Qt tr() does not translate, translate() does". It is specifically about why `tr()` behaves the way it does in PySide/PyQt, and how to avoid having to specify the context. The OPs original code example actually used `app.translate('app', 'Apple2')`, so your answer does not provide any new information. (PS: the docs you link to are for `pylupdate4`, not `pyside-lupdate`. But in any case, nothing in my answer contradicts what those docs have to say).

Comment: PS: I have now restored some previous edits to the question, so my answer should now make more sense.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah ok, I wasn't aware that that was the original question. I'll leave this answer here regardless, because it's the way to go if you want to do translation properly. I've edited away the criticism towards your post.

Comment: **This answer wins.** `QObject.tr()` is an undetonated landmine field of explosive developer pain and is guaranteed to fail in the general case for both PySide[2] and PyQt[4|5]. `QtCoreApplication.translate()` is indeed the canonical solution. I'm unsurprised but disappointed that both frameworks issue continue to *no* warnings on `tr()` calls – but they really should. My suspicion is that PyQt6 (*???*) will eventually provide a working `tr()` substitute named `tr_sane()` that behaves sanely. Until then, `tr()` should probably be considered harmful.

Comment: If you only have one context, you can leverage the `@default` context name by writing a custom `my_tr()` function that wraps `QCoreApplication.translate('@default', source_text)`.   Pass `pylupdate5` the name of the custom function:  `pylupdate5 -tr-function my_tr my.py -ts my.ts`.  If you name your custom function `tr()` you don't even need the extra argument to `pyludate5`. Additionally, If you only have one context, it's trivial to post-process the `@default` context name in .ts file to whatever it you prefer to use in my_tr().